# Execute async XMLHttpRequests in a loop and proceed when all requests have finished

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to execute asynchronous XMLHttpRequests in a `for loop`, which loads a bunch of JSONs.

To make sure that all XMLHttpRequests requests complete before calling the `nextFunction()`, I'm using `xhr.onreadystatechange`. 
This seems to work fine, but my `nextFunction()` is being executed before the last XMLHttpRequest completes.

Why is this so? And what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var arrCurrency = ['Bitcoin', 'Ethereum', 'Litecoin', 'Ripple'];
arrJSON = [];
createCurrencyArray();

function createCurrencyArray() {

  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrCurrency.length; i++) {

    var url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + arrCurrency[i] + '/?convert=EUR';

    getJSON(url, parseJSON);

    function parseJSON() {
      var a = this.responseText;
      var b = a.slice(1, -1);
      var c = JSON.parse(b);
      arrJSON.push(c);
    }
  }

  function xhrSuccess() {
    this.callback.apply(this, this.arguments);
  }

  function getJSON(url, callback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.callback = callback;
    xhr.onload = xhrSuccess;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

        count++;
        console.log('state:' + xhr.readyState + ' JSON-' + count + ' loaded')

        if (count == arrCurrency.length) {
          console.log("Done: All JSONs loaded");
          nextFunction();
        }
      }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  }
}

function nextFunction() {
  console.log(arrJSON);
  console.log('array length: ' + arrJSON.length);
  console.log('array key 0: ' + arrJSON[0]["id"]);
  console.log('array key 1: ' + arrJSON[1]["id"]);
  console.log('array key 2: ' + arrJSON[2]["id"]);
  console.log('array key 3: ' + arrJSON[3]["id"]);
}
```

Comment: Promise.all would solve this ( in jQuery $q.all(), I think )

Comment: I think that when a XHR operation is successful, onreadystate (where state == 4) fires and then onload fires.  I'm not sure why you have half your code in one and half in the other, I think you should use one xhr event handler for all your operations.

Comment: My code looks this because I'm not a pro... I've cleaned it up and added an event listener `xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {if (this.status == 200) {//SUCCESS}`. It seems working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here and process results when all requests have finished.

```js
var arrCurrency = ['Bitcoin', 'Ethereum', 'Litecoin', 'Ripple'], arrJSON = [], all = [];

function nextFunction() {  
  console.log('array length: ' + arrJSON.length);
  arrJSON.forEach((entry,idx)=>{console.log('array-key '+idx+': ' + arrJSON[idx].id); });
  console.log(arrJSON);
}

function parseJSON(jsn) {
    var obj = jsn.slice(1, -1);
    var jsnObj = JSON.parse(obj);
    arrJSON.push(jsnObj);
}
   
for(i=0; i < arrCurrency.length; i++){    
  
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){  
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
   oReq.addEventListener("load", function(xhr){ resolve(xhr);});
   oReq.addEventListener("error",  function(b){reject(this);});
   oReq.open('GET', ['https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' + arrCurrency[i] + '/?convert=EUR'].join(""), true);
  oReq.send();   
   });
    all.push(p);
} // loop end
  
Promise.all(all).then(values => {
  values.forEach(function(p){parseJSON(p.currentTarget.responseText);});
  nextFunction();
});
```